# How to anonymously donate cryptocurrency to charities which only support traditional online payments platform?

Tags: online-payment, cryptocurrency, donation

A lot of charities that I want to help support only traditional online payments system, such as GoFundMe, GoGetFunding, JustGiving, Patreon, Paypal, Payroll Giving, Stripe, ...

Is there a way to anonymously donate cryptocurrency to them? Something like a payment gateway that would donate on behalf of me after I send them cryptocurrency...

Me -> Gateway -> Traditional payments platform -> Charity

In cryptocurrency, we can send XMR to https://xmr.to/nojs/ and ask it to send equivalent BTC to the desired address.

Comment: Charities are not part of the "anonymous" world.  They are highly regulated and indeed in general follow KYC-like practices .. just like banks.  The currency is irrelevant - they don't want and can't accept donations that are (say) from criminal or shady situations.

Comment: @Fattie anonymous in charities can refer to public disclosures, anonymous in reference to cryptocurrency donations can refer to using payment network that doesn't provide surveillance. A charity that accepts bitcoin, for example and which many do, can be still be paid with Monero (XMR) and the donor will not have leaked information about their other funds. Anonymous doesn't necessarily mean that there is no party that has some details, just not public details.

Comment: hi CQM.  simply sticking to the question, third paragraph, it won't work because charities (generally) don't want funds that could be either stolen or from shady sources.  (the technology aspect is irrelevant)

Comment: @Fattie But some seems to accept donations in cryptocurrency, [for examples](https://donate.torproject.org/cryptocurrency/) Tor Project is a 501(c)(3) nonprofit which accepts Monero (XMR), Bitcoin (BTC) and more without KYC. So I guess there isn't something fundamentally illegal about having such a gateway.

Comment: @user105710 I have voted to reopen. Even the reason for closing is completely wrong. The universe of answers do not require an offsite service.

Comment: What part of the transaction do you want to keep anonymous? Hide it from the government? Hide it from the charity? Make sure you aren't on the list of donors they publish each year?

Comment: Have you researched how people anonymously donate regular old fiat money?

Comment: @RonJohn Putting money into donation box during fund raising is anonymous enough for me because of the lack of permanent record. Pedantic folks can wear a cap and sunglasses... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to talk to the charity or choose a different charity.

Look at the charities that are involved with The Giving Block which is an organization that helps charities modernize specifically to help to accept cryptocurrency and digital assets. At a future time there may be different kinds of lists, but a list is not necessary.

Other charities that don't advertise their acceptance of crypto may be used to accepting esoteric and illiquid non-cash assets, and liquid non-cash assets, so you have to ask.

But every year the field of who accepts what and how gets larger.

Answer (score 2):

To donate cryptocurrency directly to a charity, they'd need to have the capability of *holding* that cryptocurrency. Probably most charity organizations do not.

I assume the reason you'd like to do this is because you have crypto that has appreciated in value and you'd like to donate it in-kind to avoid capital gains taxes that'd be incurred by selling the cryptocurrency and donating the proceeds. If that's the case, probably your best bet is to set up a donor-advised fund. These are like brokerage accounts that you control but funds can only be used for charitable giving. Contributing to a donor advised fund is tax deductible and you can contribute assets in-kind to avoid capital gains. I'm not totally sure which donor advised funds support cryptocurrency, but a quick internet search suggests that [Fidelity Charitable](https://www.fidelitycharitable.org/giving-account/what-you-can-donate/donating-bitcoin-to-charity.html) may. If your charity doesn't support holding cryptocurrency, you can sell the asset within the donor advised fund tax-free and donate the proceeds.

The one catch is that donor advised funds typically have minimum balances to open and maintain, so if you have just a small amount of appreciated cryptocurrency, this approach may not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to donate "in kind" (whether that's crypto or stocks) to a charity which hasn't set itself up to handle that particular kind of donation may be to open a Donor Advised Fund at a service which *does* accept that sort of equity, take the tax deduction when you contribute to the DAF, and then tell the DAF to send cash to the nonprofit you really want to support. I started doing this when the list of charities I support became too large to easily fit in tax forms and the total became large enough that I preferred to donate appreciated equities. There's an account maintenance fee, but for me it's worth that cost.

I believe Fidelity Charitable can accept at least some cryptocurrencies (see https://www.fidelitycharitable.org/giving-account/what-you-can-donate/donating-bitcoin-to-charity.html). Other DAF organizations may accept these or others.